# Mysql fails to start after upgrade

Tags: 14.04, mysql

I had `mysql` working fine, and then I upgraded from 5.1 to 5.5. Now I think it was still working after the upgrade, but I'm doubting myself now that I can't get it started again.

I have looked at the other similar questions, and none solved my problem. I incorrectly backed up my database, an so any solution which involves reinstalling is not going to be helpful.

Output of `/var/log/mysql/error.log`:

```
140816 22:35:52  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 2316910
140816 22:35:52 [Note] 
140816 22:35:53 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140816 22:35:53 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140816 22:35:53 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140816 22:35:53 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
140816 22:35:53 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140816 22:35:53 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
140816 22:35:53 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140816 22:35:53 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
140816 22:35:53  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
140816 22:35:54 InnoDB: 5.5.38 started; log sequence number 2316910
140816 22:35:54 [ERROR] Aborting

140816 22:35:54  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
```

I have tried starting it several ways, and all give me the same messages (and in most cases, it just hangs on the command line, then silently fails). When running `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start`, it does show:

```
Starting MySQL database server mysqld               [fail]
```

I'm not exactly sure what the problem is, but it looks like the background threads aren't starting. Any ideas as to what to try?

**Edit:** After starting with `/usr/bin/mysqld_safe -v`, I get the following output:

```
140817 11:22:31 mysqld_safe Can't log to error log and syslog at the same time.  Remove all --log-error configuration options for --syslog to take effect.
140817 11:22:31 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
140817 11:22:31 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe: 126: /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: cannot create /var/log/mysql/error.log: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe: 1: eval: cannot create /var/log/mysql/error.log: Permission denied
140817 11:22:31 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe: 126: /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: cannot create /var/log/mysql/error.log: Permission denied
```

(I did `chmod -R 755 /var/log/mysql`, and still the same errors persist. The owner of `/var/log/mysql` is `mysql`)

When run as superuser, the errors are as follows:

```
140817 12:01:50 mysqld_safe Can't log to error log and syslog at the same time.  Remove all --log-error configuration options for --syslog to take effect.
140817 12:01:50 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
140817 12:01:50 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
140817 12:01:53 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

Comment: What exactly is added to `/var/log/mysql/error.log` when running `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start`? (From the log timestamps, I'm confused)

Comment: @VolkerSiegel - that whole error message I posted gets posted several times (it looks like it tries over and over,  but keeps failing)

Comment: Can you run it with the verbose option, like here http://rajshekhar.net/blog/archives/407-mysql-startup-debugging-tip.html or so?

Comment: @VolkerSiegel - done, see edit

Comment: Looks like `/var/log/mysql` is not owned by the same user that runs `mysqld`? Needs a `chown` then.

Comment: so would that be `chown root /var/log/mysql`?

Comment: More like `chown mysql /var/log/mysql` - what does `ls -ld /var/log/mysql` say?

Comment: `drwxr-sr-x 2 mysql adm 4096 Aug 17 07:58 /var/log/mysql` - isn't that already the owner is mysql?

Comment: Oh, wait - as which user are you running `/usr/bin/mysqld_safe -v`? should be the mysql user!

Comment: Yes, the permissions look good.